# Java - JDBC executeUpdate() not working

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am trying to insert/update/delete a row using jdbc. Inserting is working, and I only changed the query string (or **insertTableSQL**) By debugging, I suspect that **executeUpdate()** is not terminated and console does not show me any error message. (JUST BLANK)

**[EDIT]**
**The program is stuck while executeUpate() is exeucting, meaning that I cannot even see the return value**

Instead of using query string, I also tried **PreparedStatement** but no luck :(

```
String deleteRecordSQL = "DELETE mytable WHERE id = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(deleteRecordSQL);
ps.setInt(1, 6);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Full Code:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DeleteRow {

private static final String DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "";
private static final String DB_USER = "";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "";

public static void main(String[] argv) {

    try {

        deleteRecordFromDbUserTable();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}

private static void deleteRecordFromDbUserTable() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("DELETE mytable WHERE id = 6");

        System.out.println("Record is deleted!");


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                           DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}
```

}

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIS IS NOT THE OFFICIAL ANSWER, BUT THE PROBLEM IS RESOLVED SOMEHOW**

There was Java update notification, and I followed it. After update, the status of JRE System Library(JavaSE - 1.7) is changed to **unbound**. I changed Execution environment to JavaSE - 1.6 (Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.6) JRE), and the issue was resolved..weird..

There was no syntax problem

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = 6
DELETE mytable WHERE id = 6
```

If anyone can explain me how this issue could be resolved, your help would be much appreciated.

FYI.

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since its stuck it must be waiting for some resource which might be locked. 
I had faced this issue for simple update query. Here the update query was run on sql developer tool and the commit was not done.

Thanks to [a comment by Prabhmanmeet Singh on this link](https://coderanch.com/t/304569/databases/executeUpdate-updating-exception-thrown)

Comment: This is what it was for me too, an operation on the table in sqldeveloper was performed but not committed, my java code would block at executeUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't get an exception, which you don't state one way or the other, you need to examine the return value of `executeUpdate()`, which is the number of affected rows. If it was zero, no rows were deleted, probably because nothing matched the `WHERE` clause. If it was non-zero, that many rows were deleted. You certainly shouldn't be printing `"Record is deleted!"` when nothing may have happened at all. Your program may be lying to the user.

NB `insertTableSQL` is a stupid name for a variable containing an SQL `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Please ignore the name of the variable because I forgot to edit in this post haha. Btw, the problem is that the program is not terminating and stuck while it is executing executeUpdate() method.