# OJDBC ExecuteUpdate() does not return anything

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I have a small java application, and i'm trying to execute a insert-select (`insert into table1 (column) select column from table2`) using oracle jdbc driver, this sql comand inserts around 230k lines, in SQL Developer it runs in 30 minutes, but at java, when i called `ExecuteUpdate()` the method stuck and does not returns anything, more than 3 hours of execution, and the method remains stuck.

I tried to use `execute()` but the result was the same.
I tried the drivers ojdbc5, ojdbc6 and ojdbc7, without success.

I found this question: [Java - JDBC executeUpdate() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029049/java-jdbc-executeupdate-not-working) but i can't  change to weblogic.

anyone can help-me?

EDIT:
The SQL command is successful executed, when i query this on sql developer, i can see the correct result, but in java application the method remais stuck.

Comment: SQL Developer is written in Java and using the Oracle JDBC driver, too, so Java is most likely not the reason for your problem. Use the "Monitor Sessions" tool in SQL Developer to check what is going on behind the scenes. Also check if your file system has run full because of the archive logs.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to understand problem, if i can see your code. First of all, `executeUpdate("some query")` function doesn't have return value. If i remember, you can assign `int result = statement.executeUpdate("query")` If you want return values, you can use `ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("some query")` executeUpdate() always stucks while inserting a lot of rows, but 3 hours is not normal. Please show your code :)